# XMLStreamWriter vs StringBuilder or StringBuffer

Tags: java, xml, stax

Is there any substantial advantage in using a XMLStreamWriter:

```
Writer out = new StringWriter();
XMLStreamWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(out);
writer.writeStartDocument();
writer.writeStartElement("FirstElement");
```

as opposed to a StringBuilder or StringBuffer?

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("<FirstElement>");
```

I'm talking about very simple XML documents here, without namespaces.

Comment: Yes - you don't need to worry about escaping or anything else XML-specific. The very first time you find yourself having to do something XML-specific, you should run - don't walk - to the nearest XML API. In my experience, it's very easy to start with a situation where you think you won't need escaping etc, and gradually add bits and bobs until you have a horrible mess.

Comment: "This" being what? And justification for using `XMLStreamWriter`, or justification for using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @JonSkeet "This" referring to the escaping. I retracted my comment. In my case I just use StringBuilder anyways. I only added StringBuffer because some people might use it.

Comment: Yes, it's enough justification to use an XML API. It doesn't have to be `XMLStreamWriter`, but unless your code's purpose is to be an XML library, you shouldn't be writing XML escaping (etc) logic.